# Error: a url property or function must be specified

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-routing, backbone-model

These are my initial days of working on BackBone.js. I am actually stuck with the router part as i am getting an error in the console "Error: a url property or function must be specified". This is my scenario; I have a click function which dynamically forms a REST URL, and fetch the data from server accordingly.

Here is the click function code

```
function onUserClick(obj){
     var userID=$(obj).attr('id');
     window.location.href="#"+userID+"/";
     var userRouter = new UserRouter;
}
```

And I have the following code in the router

```
var userModel;
var UserRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        ":userid/":"getUsers"
    },
    getUsers:function(userid){
        var url="http://myserver.com/users/"+userid;
        userModel = new UserModel({urlRoot:url});
        var userView = new UserView({el:$(#"container")});
    }
});
var UserModel = Backbobe.Model.extend({});
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model:userModel,
    initialize:function(){
        _.templateSettings = {
            interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
            evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
        };
        this.model.fetch();
        this.model.bind("change",this.render,this);
    },
    render:function(){
        var data=this.model.toJSON();
        var userTemplate=_.template($("#userTemplate").text());
        var htmlData=userTemplate({
            "userData":data
        });
        $(this.el).html(htmlData);
    }
});
```

Can someone help me to figure out the issue here? I know i have done something wrong here and seeks an expert advice on this. A woking sample for this scenario is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some context to your error?  What have you tried to do to resolve this yet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're calling `fetch` on your model:

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: userModel,
    initialize: function() {
        // ...
        this.model.fetch();
```

But you didn't give your model a `url` property:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

The [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) method talks to the server and it uses `url` to do so:

> **url** `model.url()`
>
> Returns the relative URL where the model's resource would be located on the server. If your models are located somewhere else, override this method with the correct logic. Generates URLs of the form: `"/[collection.url]/[id]"`, falling back to `"/[urlRoot]/id"` if the model is not part of a collection.

The [default implementation for a Model's `url`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L532) looks like this:

```
url: function() {
  var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

You don't have a [`urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot), you don't have a collection to delegate the URL generation to, and you haven't overridden `url` so `urlError()` gets called and that's where your error message comes from.

Your `UserModel` needs a RESTful `url` property or function so that you can `fetch` instances from the server. Alternatively, you could create your models from data that's already available in your client-side environment (as long as you're not planning on saving anything through Backbone of course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has been helpful.